# Can anyone give me a copy of the latest token contract code?

Tags: eosio.token

The old version doesn't work, so I want to request a new version of the contract code

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here: [eosio.token](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.token/tree/main/contracts/eosio.token).

Before compiling it, you need to modify this line at the eosio.token.hpp file to your account's name.

`class [[eosio::contract(YOUR_TOKEN_ACCOUNT)]] token : public contract {`